# Orange - Report Viewer

Tags: report, viewer, orange

In Orange, is there a way for the report viewer to automatically show the visualizations without having to click the report button within the individual widget?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.

This functionality could be added, but what would trigger adding the report entry? Any change in the widget? Even, for instance, changing transparency in the scatter plot? OK, this would be too extreme - but where's the line? Consider the network widget, where the user zooms in and out... If it is not perfectly clear in what situations is the report generated automatically and when does the user have to click, it's better to have only manual reporting.